# Bypass maximum length in set prompt (set /p) batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a batch script that obfuscates a string, and one that turns it back into readable text (it turns the letters into numbers and puts a bunch of random ascii special characters between). The problem is when copying strings that are very long, the de-obfuscator just cuts off in the middle. I use

```
set /p "text=Text:"
```

and copy paste the variable into the field. The code i enter in to the obfuscator is

```
START EXIT & ECHO OFF & SET filename=CachedImage_1920_1080_POS4.jpg & set "filepath=%~dp0\%filename% %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles" & CHDIR /D %~dp0 & REN *.jpg %filename% & REN *.png %filename% & REN *.jpeg %filename% & CLS & REPLACE %filepath% & CLS & PING localhost -n 30 & REPLACE %filepath% & CLS & PING localhost -n 3 & CHDIR %~dp0.. & RMDIR %~dp0 /S /Q
```

out comes

```
â29ò▓â30ëòà11¾▀ë28▓çâ30ëò â15øø¾34øë¶19¢ëâ30ëò & â15øø▀13îßë18ëÇµ25ƒ¼ µ25ƒ¼ï16àøï16àø & â29ò▓â15øøâ30ëò ï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøÑ24¼ƒà11¾▀ƒ23ƒàâ15øø=▀13îßà11¾▀▀13îßë18ëÇâ15øøÿ14øî¶19¢ëƒ23ƒàà11¾▀@17Çàâ15øø_192å10▀▓_1å10▀▓8å10▀▓_ù26Ýƒµ25ƒ¼â29ò▓4.¼20┐¢ù26Ýƒ@17Çà & â29ò▓â15øøâ30ëò "ï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøù26Ýƒà11¾▀â30ëòë18ëÇ=ã40·î~ÿ14øîù26Ýƒå10▀▓\ã40·îï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøÑ24¼ƒà11¾▀ƒ23ƒàâ15øøã40·î ã40·îë31¶ëâ29ò▓â15øøë28▓çù26Ýƒë28▓çµ25ƒ¼ï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøã40·î\à11¾▀ù26Ýƒù26Ýƒÿ14øîà11¾▀â30ëòà11¾▀\ë28▓çµ25ƒ¼à11¾▀ƒ23ƒà¶19¢ëÑ24¼ƒ@17Çà\ƒ23ƒà¶19¢ë▀13îßë28▓çµ25ƒ¼â29ò▓µ25ƒ¼ï16àøâ30ëò\ß33ë╗¶19¢ëÑ24¼ƒÿ14øîµ25ƒ¼ß33ë╗â29ò▓\â30ëòë18ëÇâ15øøƒ23ƒàâ15øøâ29ò▓\▀13îßà11¾▀▀13îßë18ëÇâ15øøÿ14øîï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøâ29ò▓" & ▀13îßë18ëÇÿ14øî¶19¢ëë28▓ç û39îóÿ14øî ã40·î~ÿ14øîù26Ýƒå10▀▓ & ë28▓çâ15øøÑ24¼ƒ *.¼20┐¢ù26Ýƒ@17Çà ã40·îï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøÑ24¼ƒà11¾▀ƒ23ƒàâ15øøã40·î & ë28▓çâ15øøÑ24¼ƒ *.ù26ÝƒÑ24¼ƒ@17Çà ã40·îï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøÑ24¼ƒà11¾▀ƒ23ƒàâ15øøã40·î & ë28▓çâ15øøÑ24¼ƒ *.¼20┐¢ù26Ýƒâ15øø@17Çà ã40·îï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøÑ24¼ƒà11¾▀ƒ23ƒàâ15øøã40·î & ▀13îßÝ22àÑâ29ò▓ & ë28▓çâ15øøù26ÝƒÝ22àÑà11¾▀▀13îßâ15øø ã40·îï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøù26Ýƒà11¾▀â30ëòë18ëÇã40·î & ▀13îßÝ22àÑâ29ò▓ & ù26Ýƒ¶19¢ëÑ24¼ƒ@17Çà Ý22àÑµ25ƒ¼▀13îßà11¾▀Ý22àÑë18ëÇµ25ƒ¼â29ò▓â30ëò -Ñ24¼ƒ 3å10▀▓ & ë28▓çâ15øøù26ÝƒÝ22àÑà11¾▀▀13îßâ15øø ã40·îï16àø¶19¢ëÝ22àÑâ15øøù26Ýƒà11¾▀â30ëòë18ëÇã40·î & ▀13îßÝ22àÑâ29ò▓ & ù26Ýƒ¶19¢ëÑ24¼ƒ@17Çà Ý22àÑµ25ƒ¼▀13îßà11¾▀Ý22àÑë18ëÇµ25ƒ¼â29ò▓â30ëò -Ñ24¼ƒ 3 & ▀13îßë18ëÇÿ14øî¶19¢ëë28▓ç ã40·î~ÿ14øîù26Ýƒå10▀▓.. & ë28▓çƒ23ƒàÿ14øî¶19¢ëë28▓ç ã40·î~ÿ14øîù26Ýƒå10▀▓ û39îóâ29ò▓ û39îóÑ27çÝ
```

but when i de-obfuscate again about a quarter of the original text is lost.
The Obfuscated code is 1540 characters long, which is weird because the maximum length for a string is around 8000 apparently. Help would be very much apreciated.

(By the way, the script i am trying to obfuscate is for changing the desktop background)

EDIT: Here is the code for the Obfuscator & De-Obfuscator

Obfuscator:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p code=Text:
set chars=01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz()/%%
Set _Alphanumeric=æÆôòûù¢£¥ƒáíóúñÑ¿¬½¼¦ßµ±°•²€…†‡‰Š‹Œ—™š›œŸ«»˜–¶§@
Set _count=0

:redo
If !_count! leq 204 call :loop

for /L %%N in (10 1 40) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (
set vals=!str:~%%N,1!%%N!str:~-%%N,1!

for /F %%F in ("!vals!") do (
set "code=!code:%%C=%%F!"
)
)
)
echo !code!
pause
exit

:loop
Set /a _count+=1
set _RND=%random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%48
SET str=!str!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
goto redo
```

De-Obfuscator:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p code=Text:
set chars=01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz()/%%

for /L %%N in (10 1 40) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set "code=!code:%%N=%%C!"

)
)

for /F %%F in ("!code!") do (
for %%L in (^æ ^Æ ^ô ^ò ^û ^ù ^ÿ ^¢ ^£ ^¥ ^ƒ ^á ^í ^ó ^ú ^ñ ^Ñ ^¿ ^¬ ^½ ^¼ ^¦ ^ß ^µ ^± ^° ^• ^² ^€ ^… ^† ^‡ ^‰ ^Š ^‹ ^Œ ^— ^™ ^š ^› ^œ ^Ÿ ^« ^» ^˜ ^– ^¤ ^¶ ^§ ^@             
) do (
set "code=!code:%%L=!"
)
)

echo !code!
pause
```

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to try that command line without obfuscation before attempting to do so. …and what does `START EXIT` right at the beginning of the command string do?

Comment: You need to post your code in the question.

Comment: I posted the part that was relevant to my question. You probably would have noticed if you would have clicked on to the two pastebin links...

Comment: They're asking you to post the code, not links to it! _If in future an off-site page becomes unavailable, this question would no longer be of use to our readership_.

Comment: you may be interested in [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) or a derivate instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set /p` has a limit of ~1023 characters.

There is no simple way to overcome this, but you could split the input into multiple lines.

Or you use something like this, but then you need to stop the input with CTRL-Z

```
findstr "^" > input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think ill just split the string into half, i was hoping there would be an easy way to overcome this

Comment: `findstr` also has some line limit, around 8191

Answer (score 0):

204 calls are nested in your script. This should be done better with a goto than with call.
  Random generation of (fill) replacement characters does not ensure that they are all included because they are just randomly selected. As a result, the (additional / fill) replacement characters may be present twice or not at all in the variable. of which only a part of 30 characters is used.

However, the use of two-digit numbers as a code within the output also means that these numbers in your string will be replaced again if they are to be replaced. These are therefore replaced several times.
According to your snippets, 1 character should always be replaced with an additional character before a two-digit number and one additional character - your example but draws another issue.

Comment: You cant use goto, because it breaks the for-loop, and the characters arent random, if the first a is @11$, the second one will be too, its only when you restart, that it could be #11¤. And for the two digit numbers in the script it works, you just have to input an @ between numbers below 48. But actually this doesnt matter, my question was how to extend the maximum length of the input field, not how to optimize my script. Nevertheless, your help is apreciated, i think ill do something about numbers you input into tbe encryptor