# Retrieve data from NTFS alternative data stream

Tags: cmd, stream, ads, binaryfiles, ntfs

I have an ADS in a file:

```
17/03/2021  17:27               100 test2.txt
                                 10 test2.txt:1:$DATA
               1 File(s)            100 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  some bytes free
```

which I got by `type somefile > test2.txt:1` resulting in 10 byte ADS correctly.

But when I DonaldTrump it from ADS to separate file, I get extra 2 bytes (0d0a):

```
findstr /V /L W3AllLov3DonaldTrump <test2.txt:1>test.exe
```

How do I avoid this (and get a 10 byte file like the original instead of a 12 byte file)?

Answer (score 1):

It's `findstr`, which adds the line ending (`CRLF`, `0d0a`). Same with `find`, `type`, and `more`. So you can't use one of those commands. `Copy /b` would be a solution, but it doesn't accept ADS-names.

If there is just one line in the ADS (which I assume it is):

```
set /p "x="<"test2.txt:1"
<nul set /p "=%x%" >test.exe
```

Note: there is a length limit with the `set` command and I'm not sure how that reacts to non-printable characters (especially `NUL` (0x00)) (which are quite common with anything, I'd expect in an `.EXE`), so this might be of limited usage.

Comment: Yeah it's a binary file that I put in ADS and looking at extraction of original; one method of organisation instead of putting files in folders to save desktop clutter. Apart from CRLF problem, I get `line too long` error with `findstr`, which will probably be a problem with `set`.

Comment: [variable length limit 8,191](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html),[findstr line length limit 8,191](https://superuser.com/questions/1267694) and [set /p has even a limit of 1023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844883)!. I can imagine though, the two extra bytes don't hurt in a properly built `.exe`. Have you tried that? (All involved commands are built for text, so double-check for crazy things happening to binary data.  [fc /b](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) original and resulting file)

Comment: yeah I found what the extra 2 bytes were, with `fc /b`, which are not a problem; I can remove them easy; it's just that I have to do another command for it. Was looking for a way to extract the original without extra processing to remove the 2 redundant bytes. The other problem was there's nothing I found yet to remove the original without error: `set` & `find` have line limits and `more` just freezes, probably expecting some input after a screenful. `for` might also have a buffer limit. Powershell `[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes` also freezes.